# Python MySQL query not reflecting in a Tkinter widget?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, widget

How do I display the output of a MySQL query with TKinter?

**Code Snippet:**

```
 cursor.execute("SELECT bin FROM stock_lists WHERE part_number = %s", (myvar))
 self.myvar=cursor.fetchone()
 self.label4 = Label(self, text=0, textvariable=self.myvar)
```

The snippet code above *should* display the `bin` value in the `self.label4` widget. But currently the label is not displaying anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try remove `textvariable` and `assign text=self.myvar`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ways to resolve your problem:

**First option:**

First, if you want to keep the use of a Tkinter variable as you did, you need to modify its content using the  [`set()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) method:

```
 #You must declare your Tkinter variable previously in your code:
 self.tkinter_variable = StringVar()
 # Then modify your last line of code this way:
 self.label4 = Label(self, textvariable=self.tkinter_variable.set(self.myvar))
```

**Second option:**

An other option is to use the text option correctly and get rid of textvariable option especially if you do not need it to control the labels using a Tkinter variable. This means that you need to change this line:

```
self.label4 = Label(self, text=0, textvariable=self.myvar)
```

To:

```
self.label4 = Label(self, text=self.myvar)
```